# Pytorch tensor allocation much slower inside docker container

Tags: docker, pytorch, nvidia-docker

Running the snippet below takes twice as long when run inside a docker-container (keeping all python versions the same) using the Nvidia-docker runtime, then locally executed.

I tried various different base images, but they have a similar (slower) runtime. I would have expected that running code inside a Docker container does not impact runtime performance? So I feel that I'm missing something.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
import torch
def run():
    print("doing run")
    random_data = []
    for _ in range(320):
        random_data.append(np.random.randint(256, size=(1, 84, 84)))
    tensor = torch.tensor(random_data, device="cuda")
    print(tensor.shape)
n_runs = int(1e3)
runtimes = []
for i in range(n_runs):
    start = time()
    run()
    end = time()
    took = end-start
    runtimes.append(took)
    print(f"It took {took} second")
print("====")
print(f"avg_runtime: {np.average(runtimes)}")
```